# Dropdown Menu to go to specific row

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I want to use a dropdown item in cell M7 on sheet "Adjustments per cost center" to jump to specific rows on this sheet to make it more user-friendly and avoid long scrolling through the sheet.

I tried this code:

```
Sub Jump()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Adjustments per cost center")

Set rng = ws.Range("G:G").Cells.Find(ws.Range("M7"), lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then ' the item was found
    rng.Select
Else
    MsgBox "This item is not in the list", vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

1) This code is starts by clicking on a button and not by a change of the dropdown (in cell M7)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    Dim checkTarget As Range 
    Set checkTarget = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("my_named_range")) 

    If checkTarget Is Nothing Then 
        Debug.Print "not active range, exit" 
    Else 
        MsgBox "success" 
    End If 
End Sub
```

2) Major problem: The code works only if in range (G:G) the input is done as hard code and is not a result of a formula.

Many thanks for your support

Comment: Is this inside a `Workshseet_Change` event? If it is... you need to use `Worksheet_Calculate` if you want the event to fire when formulas recalculate.

Comment: It should be, how do I need to change my code ? At the end the macro should work in case of changing the dropdown....

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)

Comment: Or use the change event and check if `Target` `Intersect`s with the cell the drop down is in.

Comment: @Bigben: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim checkTarget As Range
    Set checkTarget = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("my_named_range"))
    If checkTarget Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "not active range, exit"
    Else
        MsgBox "success"
    End If

End Sub

Comment: Please [edit] your question with code, instead of posting in comments.

Comment: I tried this code above but i doesn't work....

Comment: Where did you put the change code? In the sheet code module?

Comment: I think you want to have `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` where the target is cell M7, then call your "Jump" Sub ? And have `lookin:=xlValues` in the Jump Sub for the find.